# Can not access Tomcat servlet using httpd ajp proxy in Docker

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, tomcat, mod-proxy, ajp

Docker, httpd and tomcat is new to me.

**What I want to do:** Access tomcat servlet through httpd ajp reverse proxy.

I am making two containers under same bridge network, one runs httpd, another tomcat.

**Problem:** I can not access tomcat through httpd. Httpd returns 403 error. I can access through port 8080 if I expose it to the host. I have read many articles but do not understand what I am doing wrong. Current configuration should work according to my understanding but surely I am missing something.

[image: Screenshot of error page]

Kindly give me pointers what am I doing wrong.

**My configurations and dockerfiles**
Please see the [Git repository here](https://github.com/jisandev/docker-httpd-tomcat-ajp).
I run the container by first creating image and run by following

```
# Start web container
docker run -dit --name httpd.container -p 80:80 --network extope-network httpd-101-image
# Start AP container
docker run -dit --name tomcat.container -p 8080:8080 --network extope-network --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway tomcat-101-image
```

Comment: The 403 error comes from tomcat, not httpd. Your httpd is working fine.

Comment: Why would tomcat return 403 when accessed via httpd? As accessing by 8080 port works fine.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, you may be mistaken, with the current configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes from the secret in your httpd config.

```
ProxyPass "/docs" "ajp://tomcat.container:8009/docs" secret=test_ajp_secret
ProxyPass "/manager/" "ajp://tomcat.container:8009/manager/" secret=test_ajp_secret
```

Afterwards it works.

Comment: This actually solved my problem! The documents can be more clear in this regards saying to not to use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your server.xml redirects traffic to port 8443, but,

1. doesn't handle that port (the handler is commented out)
2. the container doesn't accept traffic
   for that port.

In the httpd.conf I see "Include conf/httpd_extope.conf", but there is no httpd_extope.conf.  The http_proxy.conf tries to contact the container on port 8009, for which the above two remarks are also valid.

Comment: Thank you, I tried removing redirect port line on ajp connector, but the problem persists. By the way, in the connector configuration for 8080 port, there is also a line for redirection to same 8443 port, but i am able to access through 8080 port. Why is that?

Comment: Port 8080 is handled correctly. See another problem you have above.

Comment: Sorry i changed the file names before sharing. The file names are correct in my environment. I will fix that

Comment: That doesn't change the problem with port 8009.